# ayuda con mapa fisico

Tags: javascript, google-maps, aplicación-web

como resalto una area  de un pais con leafletjs la unica manera que he visto es usando un archivo Geojson he usado mapzen y funciona pero existe otra manera
de hacerlo esta manera el problema que tengo es que pesan mucho los archivos geojson(hasta 15mg) y me preocupa el rendimiento de la aplicacion, en la aplicacion  que estoy haciendo es sobre un mapa de mi pais ;son 18 deparmentos

aca les pongo un ejemplo asi es lo que busco
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=cortes+honduras&polygon=1&viewbox=

Comment: Lo del rendimiento lo podrías resolver de varias formas. Si el zoom está alejado descargas una versión del geojson con menor resolución ya que los detalles de la frontera no deben ser tan bien definidos. Si haces mucho zoom, puedes dividir los geojson por departamentos y, dependiendo, de los límites del mapa, descargar solo los geojson de los departamentos que entren en la vista del mapa,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ver un ejemplo de cómo dar estilos a un geojson con polígonos en http://bl.ocks.org/milkbread/7114600 y por el rendimiento no tengas miedo, con ese número de geometrías no te dará problemas. Puedes ver un ejemplo que hice para representar dinámicamente un gran número de puntos y el rendimiento no se ve afectado en http://inspidesingularity.es/vidaalciclista/movimientos.php